# How to highlight first record between time interval in Excel?

Tags: excel, time, extract, difference

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ClientID    Name    Date
1           John    5/1/19 12:00 AM
1           Andrew  5/1/19 12:16 AM
1           Robert  5/1/19 12:40 AM
2           Alex    5/2/19 12:27 AM
2           Mary    5/2/19 12:57 AM
2           Jane    5/2/19 1:20 AM
```

I'm trying to bring the "Name" of the person who spoke with the client according to ClientID (must be the same), date (same day & ignore records in 15 minutes interval from the first one in that day) in order to determine which was the first person who spoke with that client and for the next records, to show the previous person in order to determine who generated a comeback.

Also, the last record for that ClientID must be marked as "Last_record".

The expected result should look like this:

[image: expected result]

Any ideas on how to get this done in Excel?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a choose statement to detect which row of the current client's record you are on, then an index/match to find the first person dealing with the client and an aggregate to find the first row after that with a time separation of 15 minutes or more:

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(COUNTIF(A$2:A2,A2),"First Record",
INDEX(B$2:B$11,MATCH(A2,A$2:A$11,0)),
INDEX(B$2:B$11,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW(A$2:A$11)-ROW(A$2)+1)/(C$2:C$11>INDEX(C$2:C$11,MATCH(A2,A$2:A$11,0))+TIME(0,15,0)),1))),
"N/A")
```

The last record is just detecting where the client ID changes:

```
=IF(A2=A3,"N/A","Last Record")
```

[image]